# How to pre-select helm's pre-input?

Tags: helm, search, selection

In many other softwares (e.g., Chrome), when we initiate word search by Ctrl-F, the pre-input is pre-selected so that we can replace it by simply typing a new keyword, or append a new string to it by first pressing right-arrow key. Could we have the same behavior in helm (e.g., helm-swoop)?